# how set variable in python callback as variable and not inside an "output" html.Div

Tags: python, python-3.x, callback, plotly-dash

How to set a global variable inside a python callback.
I need the variable result_titolo[1] will be set as a variable outside the callback but not in a HTML.Div but inside a variable. Basically I need that result_titolo[1] will be set as a global variable: example value='1'.

```
@app.callback(Output('output_ricerca2', 'children'),
                [Input('output_ricerca', 'n_clicks')],
                #[Input('btn-submit', 'n_clicks')],
                [State('url', 'pathname')])
def update_output(clicks, pathname):
    if clicks is not None:
        result_titolo=pathname.split("/"),
        return (result_titolo[1])
```

Some help??

Comment: Setting a global variable like that is antipattern. If you need to use `result_titolo[1]` elsewhere, then either call a function and pass it in as a param, or hook up a different callback to take `Input('output_ricerca2', 'children')`.

Comment: @coralvanda
i need something like this in jquery:
`code` <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Get value on button click and show alert
    $("#myBtn").click(function(){
        var str = $("#myInput").val();
        alert(str);
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="myInput">
    <button type="button" id="myBtn">Show Value</button>
</body>
</html>

where my input variable is always available
var str = $("#myInput").val(); without any callback and so on